# Do SSL certificates on mail servers decrease likelihood of email being classified as spam?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, mail-server

If I have an SSL certificate for my mail server, will it mean that I am less likely to have my mail put into a spam box?

Currently, I am using a self-signed certificate for the server, but some of my users have complained that email they are sending often gets ranked as spam... is this connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an SSL certificate for your mail server won't make a difference. Look into DKIM, DomainKeys, and SPF records, check that you aren't on blacklists, etc. The content of your e-mail makes a big difference, too. There's a **lot** to ensuring e-mail delivery.

Comment: Chris - thanks for reply.  I am looking into DKIM as a result.  Looks like a good tutorial at http://techinterplay.com/enabled-dkim-cpanel-server.html for setting up in cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

More recently, there is also DMARC, (Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting and Conformance) this uses some of the principles of both Sender Policy Framework (SPF) and Domain Keys Identified Mail (DKIM) then adds some additional encoded information in the DNS

Answer (score 1):

The security certificate does not contribute anything in which your message goes to the inbox.
The SSL security certificate protects you that your data is encrypted when it is sent and in this way avoid the theft of information.

What determines the delivery and arrival of your messages in the inbox is:

1. reputation of your domain and email
2. reputation of your server or ip
3. implement the directives (dkim, spf, dmarc)
4. the content of the message

Answer (score 0):

If your WHM is forcing the cPanel/Webmail to use SSL, then this problem will occur for sure, and an SSL Certificate may fix it.